# SharePoint 2019(OnPrem) default error redirect customzing

Tags: error-handling, sharepoint-2019

[Default 401 message from cancel NTLM challenge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH39d.png)

[Default 404 message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83KNf.png)

I want to remove these message for my customer company's compliance reason.
Is there any way remove it(shows blank) or custom page redirect?

1. Set wss/VirtualDirectories/80/web.config  section to error 401/404
2. Try to default global.asax customizing for the Applicaiton_Start override. - can't find way.